# Selecionar a data mais recente de cada grupo no r

Tags: r, data

Tenho esses dados

```
data;code
18/02/2020;C106
05/04/2018;C107
11/09/2016;C107
16/02/2019;C109
11/03/2020;C110
04/03/2020;C114
18/02/2020;C114
06/02/2020;C121
```

gostaria de selecionar a data mais recente de cada code, assim:

```
data;code
18/02/2020;C106
05/04/2018;C107
16/02/2019;C109
11/03/2020;C110
04/03/2020;C114
06/02/2020;C121
```

tentei usar

```
tapply(data$data, data$code, max)
```

e apareceu esse erro

```
Error in Summary.factor(7L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que funções como máximo e mínimo possam ser aplicadas, precisa primeiro converter suas datas de character/factor para uma classe numérica, como POSIX:

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
  data;code
  18/02/2020;C106
  05/04/2018;C107
  11/09/2016;C107
  16/02/2019;C109
  11/03/2020;C110
  04/03/2020;C114
  18/02/2020;C114
  06/02/2020;C121",
  sep = ';', header = TRUE)

dados$data <- as.POSIXct(dados$data, format = '%d/%m/%Y')

> max(dados$data)
[1] "2020-03-11 -03"
```

Para selecionar a data mais recente para cada code, pode usar aggregate:

```
> aggregate(data ~ code, dados, max)
  code       data
1 C106 2020-02-18
2 C107 2018-04-05
3 C109 2019-02-16
4 C110 2020-03-11
5 C114 2020-03-04
6 C121 2020-02-06
```